# Create table as - takes really long time

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a table using:

```
create table tbl_data_separated as
    with DTE as
    (
        select file_name, 
               to_char(file_content) as file_content -- preconvert the clob to a varchar
        from tbl_data
    )
    SELECT file_name,
           file_content,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) r_id,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) p_id_,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) batch_num,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) service_id,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) id_qualifier,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1) flag,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 7, NULL, 1) n_code,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 8, NULL, 1) p_name
    FROM dte
```

In file_content, the pipe delimited has more than 150 such values which I need to compare using REGEX.

The table - tbl_data has more than 400K rows. When I run the above query, the estimated time it shows is 36 hours.

Is it possible to optimize it so it can be done faster? I'm thinking of creating a table and inserting rows. What would be the best way to speed it up?

Comment: Regular expressions look pretty, but can be slow - especially when there's a lot of data to deal with.Try to rewrite it using SUBSTR + INSTR combination.

Comment: Do you know how I can rewrite using substr + instr?

Comment: Try running the query with something like `where rownum < 10` and then `where rownum < 1000`.  Perhaps the estimated execution time is wrong.

Comment: can you please show a sample line from the file_content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code  .. why not create directly

```
create table tbl_data_separated as
SELECT file_name,
        to_char(file_content),
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) r_id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) p_id_,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) batch_num,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) service_id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) id_qualifier,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1) flag,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 7, NULL, 1) n_code,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 8, NULL, 1) p_name
from tbl_data
```

Comment: would it speed up the execution? I'm running this for over 10 mins and it is still executing.

Comment: Yes should speed  execution  .. but i can't  how much